# How to solve two coupled nonlinear Schrodinger equations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, pde, nonlinear-functions

The two coupled equations are as follows: where i->sqrt(-1); 'u_t' refers to the first order derivative w.r.t. the time 't', 'u_z' is the first order derivative w.r.t. 'z', similarly, 'u_tt' means second order derivative w.r.t. time.

```
|u|^2 is u*conjugate(u).

i*u_z-a*u_tt+|u|^2*u+kv=i*b*(u+c*u_tt)

i*v_z-a*v_tt+|v|^2*v+ku=i*b*(v+c*v_tt)
```

I have solved such single equation, but how to solve such two-coupled equations in MATLAB?

Comment: How did you solve the single equation in Matlab? Please show your code rather than equations (this is a programming site which is why it unfortunately doesn't support TeX). And what are you actually solving for? Are you doing this symbolically or numerically?

Comment: I am solving for amplitudes u and v NUMERICALLY.

Comment: Voting to close, as this does not include the edits requested two years ago, and as such does not contain enough information to answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the link [here](http://phys.thu.edu.tw/~kkng/matlab2011/html7/chap7.html#47)

> Partial differential equations with pdepe
>
> MATLAB's pdepe solves a class of parabolic/elliptic PDE systems. The
>   time-dependent Schrodinger equation is an example of parabolic PDE
>   while the Poisson equation is an example of elliptic PDE. We will not
>   discuss the use of pdepe in the class but refer you to the MATLAB's
>   documentation for the details.

Looks like your best bet is to look at `pdepe` as an example of a parabolic PDE.